# Google Anaytics Reporting API from Cloud Function with Google Managed Key

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-functions, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to use the Google Analytics reporting API from a cloud function in order to integrate the Google Analytics reporting into my company's existing Looker dashboards.  I would prefer to use Google managed keys, however, the Python3.7 runtime does not allow me to use the google.auth.app_engine.Credentials() function to get the credentials that I need to create the service object.  How can I create a analytics reporting service Object from Cloud Functions using a Google Managed Key?

This is the code that I've tried to adapt from code that worked in my local environment (It's pretty much exactly what's in the example from the quickstart documentation apart from the credentials, metrics and dimensions.  Ultimately, I'll end up dropping the retrieved data in a bigQuery dataset but for now I'm just using print functions to test the application:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from google.auth import app_engine


VIEW_ID = '**********'


def initialize_analyticsreporting():
  #Retrive credentials from app enging default service account   
  credentials = app_engine.Credentials()


  # Build the service object.
  analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

  return analytics


def get_report(analytics):

"""
    Query the Google Analytics Reporting API to return Impressions, clicks, cost and conversions
    per day from either Google Ads, SA360, DV360 or Campaign manager
"""
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '2020-03-19', 'endDate': '2020-03-19'}],
          'metrics': [
                        # Google Ads metrics

                        # {'expression': 'ga:impressions'},
                        # {'expression': 'ga:adClicks'},
                        # {'expression': 'ga:cost'},
                        # {'expression': 'ga:costPerTransaction'},

                        # Campaign Manager Metrics

                        # {'expression': 'ga:dcmImpressions'},
                        # {'expression': 'ga:dcmClicks'},
                        # {'expression': 'ga:dcmCost'},
                        # {'expression': 'ga:dcmFloodlightQuantity'}

                        # DV360 Metrics

                        {'expression': 'ga:dbmImpressions'},
                        {'expression': 'ga:dbmClicks'},
                        {'expression': 'ga:dbmCost'},
                        # {'expression': 'ga:dbmConversions'}


                        # SA360 Metrics

                        # {'expression': 'ga:dsImpressions'},
                        # {'expression': 'ga:dsClicks'},
                        # {'expression': 'ga:dsCost'},
                        # {'expression': 'ga:uniquePurchases'}


                        ],
          'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:date'}]
        }]
      }
  ).execute()


def print_response(response):
  """Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.

  Args:
    response: An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
  """
  for report in response.get('reports', []):
    columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])

    for row in report.get('data', {}).get('rows', []):
      dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
      dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

      for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
        print(header + ': ' + dimension)

      for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
        print('Date range: ' + str(i))
        for metricHeader, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
          print(metricHeader.get('name') + ': ' + value)


def main(request):
  analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
  response = get_report(analytics)
  print_response(response)
```

Comment: Hello, it's uncelar to me why you are mixing App Engine and Cloud Functions. Looking at [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-py) seems like you just need to add your `client_secrets.json` file along with your code

Comment: @Chris32, thanks for the response.  The default service account for a cloud function is the App Engine default service account so it seems to me that the two are inherently related.  As I mentioned in my original post, the ultimate goal here is to use Google Managed Keys.  If I generated, stored and referenced the `client_secrets.json`  file, I wouldn't be satisfying that requirement.

Comment: I'm looking to achieve the same, although in Node. @Domonitor just double-checking  did you have to enable (via gcloud console) the Google Analytics API and then add permissions to App Engine default service account allowing it to access Google Analytics API?